# Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference Umbraco

Tags: c#, umbraco7

Okay so I am completely stumped as to why I am getting this error. I am using umbraco CMS ver 7.5.14. Here is a screen shot of the error itself.

[image]

I have tried all of the obvious things that can cause this. I made sure my alias name was correct, I made sure there was content in that content node, and I tried clearing the cache. What's strange is we have a test site that has the same exact code and it works. I am not sure when this broke but I have no idea what to do next and any help would be appreciated. This is the block of code that the site breaks at

```
dynamic _CurrentPage = CurrentPage;
if (CurrentPage.DocumentTypeAlias == "morrellsProduct_Copy")
{
    _CurrentPage = CurrentPage.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<Umbraco.Web.Models.DynamicPublishedContent>>("copiedProduct").First();
}
```

Comment: Maybe to better pinpoint the issue you could 1-try to use the Typed version of currentpage:  IPublishedContent currentPage = Model.Content;  2-Republish the entire site by right-clicking on the Content panel (in content Section) and selecting republish entire site

Answer (score 0):

So apparently this was caused by us running the site on 2 separate servers. The dev above me told me they figured out that much, but they never told me a solution for it.